# Creating object in JS that is passed into IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, javascript, object-oriented, jquery

I am working on a web page where I am creating a JS object using `{}` and `[]`. This object is passed into a handler

> I wanted to see if there is any more way to write this method. Its a lot of code and just wanted to make sure there is no better way to do this?

My logic

Is to build the object is JS and then pass it into the `Handler` to be `Deserialize` and then saved into the db.

```
function saveLongAnswerText() {
    console.log('%c saveLongAnswerText ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');


    if ($("#form1").valid()) {


        MeetingPollingQuestion = {};
        MeetingPollingQuestion.MeetingPollingId = $("#hfMeetingPollingId").val();
        MeetingPollingQuestion.MeetingPollingQuestionType = "LongAnswerText";
        MeetingPollingQuestion.SequenceOrder = 2;
        MeetingPollingQuestion.MeetingPollingParts = [];

        MeetingPollingParts = {};
        MeetingPollingParts.Type = "Question";
        MeetingPollingParts.MeetingPollingPartsValues = [];

        MeetingPollingPartsValues = {};
        MeetingPollingPartsValues.Type = "Question";
        MeetingPollingPartsValues.QuestionValue = $("#editorLongAnswerText").data("kendoEditor").value();

        MeetingPollingParts.MeetingPollingPartsValues.push(MeetingPollingPartsValues);
        MeetingPollingQuestion.MeetingPollingParts.push(MeetingPollingParts);

        console.log(MeetingPollingQuestion);

        Metronic.blockUI({ boxed: true, message: "Saving Question.." });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ManagePolling.ashx',
            data: { "PollingQuestion": JSON.stringify(MeetingPollingQuestion), "Action": "SaveQuestion" },
            datatype: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.resultStatus.ResultCode == "1") {
                    toastr.success("Saved successfully", "Success");


                }
                if (data.resultStatus.ResultCode == "2")
                    toastr.warning(data.resultStatus.Message, "Warning");
                if (data.resultStatus.ResultCode == "3")
                    toastr.warning(data.resultStatus.Message, "Error");
                Metronic.unblockUI();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                toastr.error('An error has occured! \n' + data.resultStatus.Message);
                Metronic.unblockUI();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Handler

```
 string jsonData = context.Request.Form["PollingQuestion"];
 var MeetingPollingQuestion = new Model.MeetingPollingQuestion();
 var MeetingPollingParts = new List<Model.MeetingPollingParts>();
 var MeetingPollingPartsValues = new List<Model.MeetingPollingPartsValues>();

 MeetingPollingQuestion.MeetingPollingParts = MeetingPollingParts;

 MeetingPollingQuestion = Deserialize<Model.MeetingPollingQuestion>(jsonData);
```

Comment: Is this correct: `MeetingPollingPartsValues.Type = "Question";`?

Comment: I think that will be changed at some point.

Comment: From what perspective are you expecting a review?

Comment: How I could possibly improve the code quality?

Comment: @Jefferson Thank you for the bounty! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Client-side

#### Prefer fail fast

- Rather than guarding the whole object creation and the ajax communication logic with a condition `if ($("#form1").valid())` please prefer early exit

  - `if (!$("#form1").valid()) return;`

#### Prefer object and collection initializer

- Rather than using value assignment you can use object initializer to avoid repetitive code

```
const MeetingPollingQuestion = {
    MeetingPollingId: $("#hfMeetingPollingId").val(),
    MeetingPollingQuestionType: "LongAnswerText",
    SequenceOrder: 2,
    MeetingPollingParts: [
        {
            Type: "Question",
            MeetingPollingPartsValues: [
                {
                    Type: "Question",
                    QuestionValue: $("#editorLongAnswerText").data("kendoEditor").value()
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

#### Try to avoid mixing `stringify` and object initializer

- This line seems really odd to me

```
data: { "PollingQuestion": JSON.stringify(MeetingPollingQuestion), "Action": "SaveQuestion" }
```

- I would suggest to use object initializer first and then `stringify` it

```
data: JSON.stringify({ PollingQuestion: MeetingPollingQuestion, Action: "SaveQuestion" })
```

#### Naming

- I would suggest to consolidate your naming strategy because even in a simple line you have Pascal and camel Casing as well

```
data.resultStatus.ResultCode
```

- It is minor but please also try to consolidate the usage of `'` and `"`

#### Please prefer switch

- Rather than having 3 if branches (`.ResultCode == "1"` ... `.ResultCode == "3"`) please prefer to use switch

```
switch (data.resultStatus.ResultCode) {
    case "1": toastr.success("Saved successfully", "Success"); break;
    case "2": toastr.warning(data.resultStatus.Message, "Warning"); break;
    case "3": toastr.warning(data.resultStatus.Message, "Error"); break;
}
```

### Server-side

- The `MeetingPollingPartsValues` variable is not used
- I think the `MeetingPollingParts` variable is not needed because you overwrite the entire `MeetingPollingQuestion` object
- So, the entire method could be simplified for the following line

```
var meetingPollingQuestion = Deserialize<Model.MeetingPollingQuestion>(context.Request.Form["PollingQuestion"]);
```

Comment: can I do a loop in the object initializer?

Comment: @Jefferson As far as I know, you can not

Comment: I added that Addition object would I not be able to create the const ?

Comment: @Jefferson Here at code review we don't modify / extend the original question after a review has been placed. We encourage people to create a follow up question and link them.

Comment: Ok I will do that thanks

Comment: I created a new post  with that method https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280364/how-to-use-object-initializer-and-use-const